# Progress bar working on Android API 23, but not 21 or 22

Tags: java, android

Here is the xml portion:

```
<ProgressBar
  android:layout_width="50dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:padding="15dp"
  android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
  android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
  android:visibility="gone"
  android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorPrimary"
  android:id="@+id/progressBar"
  android:indeterminate="true" />
```

I am using this to show and hide the progress bar:

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

This is working just as I want it to on newer phones, but on API 21 and 22 the progress bar is never made visible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Adding `android:indeterminateTintMode="src_in"` fixed it:

```
<ProgressBar
  android:layout_width="50dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:padding="15dp"
  android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
  android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
  android:visibility="gone"
  android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorPrimary"
  android:indeterminateTintMode="src_in"
  android:id="@+id/progressBar"
  android:indeterminate="true" />
```